# Prevent touch events on subviews of scrolling UIScrollView in iOS7

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios7, uicontrol

I have a UIControl inside a UIScrollView. In my UIControl's `init`, I rig up some touch event handlers, e.g.

```
[self addTarget:_delegate
         action:@selector(touchedDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

iOS6 and iOS7 behave differently when I do the following:

1. Swipe the UIScrollView to start scrolling
2. Tap the UIScrollView to stop scrolling

In iOS6, my app continues to behave as intended: the tap at step #2 does **not call** `touchedDown` -- the UIScrollView swallows the touch event as it immediately stops scrolling.

But in iOS7, the UIScrollView stops scrolling as expected, while `touchedDown` **is still called**.

Was there a documented API change? I'd like my app to behave identically to iOS6 in iOS7.

Comment: Same here with UIButtons on a UIScrollView. In iOS6 you can swipe the UIScrollView by grabbing a button and the UIControlEventTouchDown will not be called on the button. In iOS7 UIControlEventTouchDown WILL be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very elegant, but in the absence of any better ideas, here's what's working for me now:

- On the UIScrollView, set `canCancelContentTouches` to `YES` and `delaysContentTouches` to `NO`.
- In the UIScrollViewDelegate, toggle the UIScrollView's subview's `userInteractionEnabled` property when the UIScrollView scrolls:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [_contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate) {
        [_contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [_contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

- Subclass the UIScrollView and implement:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{
    return YES;
}
```

- Subclass the UIControl and implement `touchesCancelled:withEvent` to reverse whatever the `UIControlEventTouchDown` handler does:

```
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //custom logic
}
```

Answer (score 9):

workaround for iOS 7

```
@interface UIScrollViewFixed : UIScrollView

@end

@implementation UIScrollViewFixed

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (self.isDragging || self.isDecelerating) {
        return self;
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Comment: Works great for iPhone, not on iPad it seems though

Answer (score 4):

Just replace the event type

`UIControlEventTouchDown` must be `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`

Comment: Actually, this is brilliant! I was looking at difficult solutions like implementing an hitTest but this does just wat i need. (Although it's not really an answer to the initial question)

Comment: great, it's what i'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Same here with UIButtons on a UIScrollView. This is my solution for now.

Instead of using the contents UIControlEventTouchDown event:

```
[button addTarget:_delegate
         action:@selector(touchedDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

I implemented the UIResponder touchesEnded method in my content UIViewController:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
// my scroll content touch logic
}
```

If the user touches the content and starts dragging the touchesEnded handler will not be called. The UIResponder touchesCanceled method will.

If the user does not drag the UIscrollview the touchesEnded handler is fired, which can be used for touch logic.